# Logstash not loading complete data from oracle to Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Am trying to load oracle data into elasticsearch, its almost 300k records are there after joining 5 table. But after the execuation of logstash config file only `79511` documents are available in elasticsearch.

I tried twice, but am getting the same results. I cross verifed in Oracle and am sure that am having `300k` records almost.

If i put `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` then its taking long hours to compelte the process.

Any idea, about this issue.

Please find my logstash config file ( i didnt include the sql query here).

```
input {
      jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc8.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1525/demodb"     
        jdbc_user => "demo"
        jdbc_password => "1234567"
        jdbc_fetch_size => "50000"
        statement => "" 
        }
    }

    output {

        elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "replacement_local101"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        }

    }
```

Comment: Any relevant information in your elasticsearch log ?

Comment: According to the docs this input would be executed just ONCE. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't specify configuration for `schedule`,

> Input from this plugin can be scheduled to run periodically according
>   to a specific schedule. This scheduling syntax is powered by
>   rufus-scheduler. The syntax is cron-like with some extensions specific
>   to Rufus (e.g. timezone support ).

by default, it runs only once,

> There is no schedule by default. If no schedule is given, then the
>   statement is run exactly once.

You need to provide `schedule` option. For instance, following will run every second,

```
schedule => "* * * * *"
```

You can read more about [syntax here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_scheduling_2)